# Как получить диаграмму в Excel по ячейке на которой она расположена?

Tags: delphi, excel

Я занимаюсь выгрузкой данных в таблицы и диаграммы Excel 2003. На листе есть десяток диаграмм и мне нужно по очереди их сконфигурировать.

В настоящий момент я получаю диаграмму Excel по ее порядковому номеру (`aId`) вот так:

```
sheet := Excel.ActiveWorkBook.Sheets[aSheetName]; // Выбираем лист
sheet.ChartObjects[aId].Activate;                 // Активируем aChartId диаграмму
chart := Excel.ActiveWorkBook.ActiveChart;        // Получаем диаграмму для работы
```

Проблема в том, что порядок/очередность диаграмм явно в Excel не виден, и при вставке новых диаграмм, приходится их все по очереди вырезать/вставлять, чтобы их индексы шли по порядку (например сверху-вниз).

Вопрос, как получить диаграмму зная ячейку над которой она расположена? (при условии что над ячейкой только 1 диаграмма). Что-то типа `chart := sheet.ChartObjects.FindByCell(x, y);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент, работающее решение - перебрать все диаграммы и проверить попадает ли ячейка в их область:

```
// Диаграммы идут от 1 до Count
for I := 1 to sheet.ChartObjects.Count do
begin
  // Сохраняем область диаграммы в прямоугольник `r`
  r := TXLRange.New(
    TXLCell.New(sheet.ChartObjects[I].TopLeftCell.Address),
    TXLCell.New(sheet.ChartObjects[I].BottomRightCell.Address));

  // Проверяем ячейку на вхождение в прямоугольник
  if r.Contains(aChartCell) then
  begin
    // Получаем искомую диаграмму
    sheet.ChartObjects[I].Activate;
    chart := aExcel.ActiveWorkBook.ActiveChart;
  end;
end;
```

P.S. `TXLRange` и `TXLCell` это примитивные структуры для хранения прямоугольника и ячейки.